# How can I log CRD reads in a GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

According to GKE, I can [enable cluster audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging) from the `k8s.io` API, which will forward cluster events to Cloud Logging. However, I'm unable to find RBAC logs for read requests on custom resources.

Specifically, if I have a CR `foo`, I seem to only be able to view `create` and `delete` events on `foo`. `get` and `list` are separate permissions as well (in both IAM and cluster RBAC), but those calls don't seem to be audited.

Is there a way to see those requests, and their responses, or is that not possible?

It's weird because the cluster's own `kube-apiserver.log` seems to log those requests:

> `... httplog.go:109] "HTTP" verb="GET" URI="/apis/foo.io/v1/namespaces/foo-ns/custom-resource/foo" latency="26.286746ms" userAgent="kubectl/v1.xx.x (linux/amd64)" audit-ID="baz" srcIP="1.2.3.4:55555" resp=200`

Comment: Is your problem resolved?